# Replacing null value in XML

Tags: java, xml

I am using below mentioned code to write comma separated values in xml from arraylist.

```
   String commaSeparated = String.join(",", list);
Element n= doc.createElement("value");
n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(commaSeparated));
```

My arraylist contains some null values which as represented as follows:

```
<value>1,2,3,null,4,5,null,6</value>
```

I want to replace this null by some other value say 'a'.

I am using following code to do this:

```
if(commaSeparated==null){
commaSeparated="a";
}
```

but still I am getting null values instead of expected output.

Expected output:

```
<value>1,2,3,a,4,5,a,6</value>
```

Please help

Comment: Hard to know because the relevant code is incomplete, but my guess is that "null" (a string value) is not the same as null.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and change:

```
if(commaSeparated==null){ // the complete string is not null
    commaSeparated="a"; //never reached
}
```

to

```
commaSeparated=commaSeparated.replaceAll("null","a"); //replaces all null substrings with 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation - you probably missed that commaSeparated is this final string with values splited by commas. So trying to find if it's null is not really a solution.

You can do it on final string or you can check every element in list and create new one with your own values when expected f. e.

```
List<String> formattedList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String element : list) {
    if(element == null){
       formattedList.add("a");
    }else{
       formattedList.add(element);
    }
}
```

now you can put `formattedList` to the `String.join`.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace null values before, for exemple :

```
list.replaceAll(s -> s == null ? "a" : s);
    String commaSeparated =String.join(",", list);
```